# How to create a listview inside a listview?

Tags: android

I'm learning programming in android studio, I want to make clickable list view and when one of the item is clicked other list is shown underneath that clicked list item and everything else is pushed down, I already have some ideas how to make that but I don't know is there any layout item for that purpose or I have to make it by myself? Thank you.

Comment: Search for ` android expandablelistview`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Expandable ListView and here how it works:

Your activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/myExpandableListView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:indicatorLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
    android:divider="@android:color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

then the List Group or the header of each expandable list:

```
list_header_group.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:textColor="@android:color/blue"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

then the child items underneath each group header:

```
list_item_child.xml


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandedListItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

your data init should be like weather you put it in a different java class or make it as a method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListDataInit {
    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> Books = new ArrayList<String>();
        books.add("Programming");
        books.add("Stories");
        books.add("Kids");
        books.add("Fiction");

        List<String> movies= new ArrayList<String>();
        movies.add("Action");
        movies.add("Cartoon");
        movies.add("Others");

        List<String> toys = new ArrayList<String>();
        toys.add("Brand 1");
        toys.add("brand 2");

        expandableList.put("books", books);
        expandableList.put("mvies", movies);
        expandableList.put("toys", toys);
        return expandableList;
    }
}
```

your adapter should look like this:

CustomExpAdapter.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

    public CustomExpAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                       HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

the MainActivity.java should look pretty much like this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    List<String> expandableListTitle;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.myExpandableListView);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                                + " -> "
                                + expandableListDetail.get(
                                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some small edits are needed here.
instead of `ExpandableListDataPump.getData()` use `ExpandableListDataInit.getData()`

instead of 
`CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail)`
use  `CustomExpAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail)`